# swift extension about protocol

Tags: swift3, protocols, extension-methods

How to understand bellow code, when i annotation '`func makeMargherita()`' of **Pizzeria Protocol**, the result is

```
["tomato", "mozzarel"]
["tomato", "basil", "mozzarel"]
```

But when `func makeMargherita()` work, it will print:

```
["tomato", "basil", "mozzarel"]
["tomato", "basil", "mozzarel"]
```

How to understand this code?

```
protocol Pizzeria{
  func makePizza(ingredients: [String])
    //func makeMargherita()
}

extension Pizzeria{
func makeMargherita() {
    return makePizza(ingredients: ["tomato", "mozzarel"])
 }
}

struct Lombardis: Pizzeria{

func makePizza(ingredients: [String]) {
    print(ingredients)
  }
func makeMargherita() {
    return makePizza(ingredients: ["tomato", "basil", "mozzarel"])
  }
}

let lombardis1: Pizzeria = Lombardis()
let lombardis2: Lombardis = Lombardis()
lombardis1.makeMargherita()
lombardis2.makeMargherita()
```

Comment: So what's the issue?

Comment: See [Reasons to include function in protocol definition vs. only defining it in the extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34777926/2976878) – defining the requirement in the protocol allows for dynamic dispatch.

Comment: @Hamish thank you. That was a really helpful answer.